# fork n children and send them a word

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, fork

I have an assignment where I have to create n children.The parent will send them each a word.They will modify it and print it. I've tried creating pipes for each child then send every one of them a word.But this is the output of my program:

```
1 child begins
2 child begins
1 child ends
3 child begins
4 child begins
2 child ends
5 child begins
3 child ends
4 child ends
5 child ends
End parent
```

And this is my program:

```
int main()
{
ifstream f("in.txt");
int n=5;//n children
int p[n][2];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    if(pipe(p[i])<0){
        perror("pipe error");
        exit(1);
    }

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    pid_t pid=fork();
    if(pid<0){
        perror("fork error");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(pid==0){//i child

        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
            close(p[j][1]);

        char word[256];
        int size;

        cout<<i+1<<" child begins"<<endl;

        while(read(p[i][0],&size,sizeof(int))>0){//first I get the size of the word
            read(p[i][0],word,size*sizeof(char));//then the word
            word[i%(size-1)] = '-';//make some changes to it
            cout<<i+1<<"child "<<word<<endl;}   

        cout<<i+1<<" child ends"<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    if(pid>0){
        close(p[i][0]);
    }
}
char word[100];
int size;
int j=0;

while(f>>word){
    size=strlen(word);

    write(p[j][1],&size,sizeof(int));
    write(p[j][1],word,100);
    j++;
}

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    close(p[i][1]);

while(wait(NULL) > 0){};
cout<<"End parent"<<endl;
exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I think you should tag this as C++, not C.

Comment: `write(p[j][0]` Should be `write(p[j][1]`.

Comment: What exactly is your point in declaring a two dimensional array for a pipe? Is it a correct method ?  If yes, Please explain the motto behind checking the error condition of that pipe for it's single dimension.

Comment: p[i][0] will be the read end of the i child and p[i][1] will be the write end of the child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original post you were mistakenly writing to the read end of the pipe in your parent code. I see you have now changed this - the relevant lines go from:

```
write(p[j][0],&size,sizeof(int));
write(p[j][0],word,100);
```

To:

```
write(p[j][1],&size,sizeof(int));
write(p[j][1],word,100);
```

Additionally, you're not really doing the right thing with your word length. I recommend these further changes, so the word coming out at the read end is correctly null-terminated and has no trailing garbage:

```
write(p[j][1],&size,sizeof(int));
write(p[j][1],word,size+1);
```

I was able to recreate your original issue, and having tested the code with these changes and it works as you would expect.